# NetCore: How to handle request from dynamic subdomain?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to handle a request from dynamic subdomain?

For example there is request `customer1.mysite.com/manage` or `customer2.mysite.com/manage`.

What should I put inside my `Startup.cs`?

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ???
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ???
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ???
}
```

I want to redirect the subdomain request to my controller according to the dynamic subdomain.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{customer?}");
});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: that is not how a website works and that is not how dns works.... in DNS the first part of the domain is the host and should point to an actual host machine or load balancer.  each host should be a separate app unless they are aliases of the same app.  the "routable" parts of the url start after the domain name... meaning after the .com.  the first slash is the root of your site

Comment: furthermore if you have to rely on host names to route to different logic then in my opinion your app is following an antipattern.  if your "manage" controller is the same for all customers than its just a matter of properly configuring your DNS to point at the same machine.

Comment: `customer1.mysite.com/manage or customer2.mysite.com/manage` will not even go to the project.If you want to go to the project,the url will be like `https://localhost:{port}/xxxx`,and in the project,you can only change the path after `localhost:{port}`.